What does the phrase 'sense of hunger' mean?
I have seen the phrase 'sense of humor', as in 'she has a great sense of humor', meaning she can understand and enjoy jokes.
But what does 'sense of hunger' mean?
For example, in the sentence, 'did your sense of hunger come from (blank)', where blank can be a place, as in, "Did your sense of hunger come from the exploring the bustling market?", what does the phrase/question actually mean?

A feeling of great hunger,desire (or greed) for some kind of success? One saw a similar expression in the 1990s in financial circles. I started out very hungry and wanting to achieve financial success, but interestingly enough after you’ve attained it, it’s about the chase.

The two aren't related anyway. If you've just heard a few good jokes, it doesn't satisfy your sense of humour, which is an innate quality. You still have a sense of humour.

If dad-jokes be the food of humor, dad on, that the sense may sicken and so die.

"Sense of hunger" is much less used in colloquial English, though according to Ngram, it was found in more works between 1800 and 1900.
It obviously means "increased appetite," "improved appetite," or "craving," from that context, and Ngram indicates "increased appetite' is currently about 10 times more common.

"I have a sense of hunger" is usually just another way of saying "I'm hungry". I have the sensation of hunger. It is used sometimes in colloquial English, but the alternative is far more common.
Another meaning, which I've never heard used, could be "I have the ability to detect that I need food" similar to the sense of sight "I have the ability to detect light".

@MariosAthanasiou Thank you for the vote. however I cannot really comment on your answer. You seem to have already had an extensive interchange with 3 other contributors, all of whom I know by reputation, and I can't see much wrong with what they say. Their expertise in English is probably greater than mine.
